# problem with use of val() in jQuery sometimes failing and setting elements with array id's

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, validation

I have a project where a form is required for inputs for a week, so for efficiency elsewhere an array of inputs is used (i.e. start[0] etc) this seems to have exacerbated the issue.

The problem is when validating a form where some inputs are given initial values (its an update) jQuery only returns those initial values instead of changed ones unless use of 'this' is feasible. I found to resolve that I had to use:

```
$(".weekdays").change(function(){
            var newval = $(this).attr('value');
            $(this).attr('value', newval);
                });
```

Which seems a crazy thing to have to do! Its here I found using `$(this).val(newval);` always fails except when setting initial values, though its the common given solution?

In the same vein setting check-boxes seems also problematical, using:

```
var id = $(this).attr('pid');
$("#choice["+id+"]").prop('checked', false);
$("#choiceLabel["+id+"]").css('background-image','url("images/Open.png")');
```

Always fails, yet reverting to javascript with:

```
var id = $(this).attr('pid');
document.getElementById("choice["+id+"]").checked = false;
document.getElementById("choiceLabel["+id+"]").style.backgroundImage = 'url("images/Open.png")';
```

Works fine!
So does jQuery not like inputs with id's in array form? or am I getting things wrong somewhere?

Comment: If you want the current value of an input, you want to use `val()` which will get the value from the element property.  The `attr('value')` will get whatever the attribute was when it loaded on the page, or what it has been changed to with `attr('value', newValue)` later on

Comment: Just for total clarity, can you edit your post and hit the `<>` button or type Ctrl+M and make a working snippet of the issue you are seeing?

Comment: Oooooh, or I may know what it is.  You have an invalid selector.  `[]` are special characters in selectors, denoting attribute selections.  So `#choice[13]` would be looking for an element with an id of `choice` **and** has an attribute of "13", which is not valid.  (ex.  `<div id="choice" 13="something">`)

Comment: In such a situation where you want the `[]` to be considered as part of the id selector for jquery, you have to escape them.  `#choice\\["+ id +"\\]`

Comment: I was using <code>val()</code> within the validation, which is where it was returning the initial instead of changed value, when I've tested <code>attr('value', newValue)</code> in the workaround script it seems to hold the new? unless I`m looking at the wrong time?

Comment: Having found this piece [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr] I'm a little clearer, I note its stated the behaviour of `attr()` has been changed though its not clear just how. Currently my initial code snippet resolves the `val()` problem and I'm not sure what else would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When attempting to select an element with an id that contains special characters, such as `[]`, you have to remember to escape them for jQuery.  For instance..

```js
var id = 12;

console.log(
  $('#choice\\['+ id +'\\]').get()
);


console.log(
  $('#choice[data-something]').get()
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="choice[12]">weee</div>
<div id="choice" data-something>dang!</div>
```

Otherwise, jQuery will treat them as special characters, in this case, assuming you are trying to find an element that has an id **and** has an attribute matching your variable value.

Comment: Thanks for that, makes sense. Would you mind explaining why it is double escaped (\\) ?

Comment: Because it's double escaped, ^_^.  The first slash, escapes the second slash, for the string construction.  And then that slash, which is now treated as a literal slash, escapes the `[` or `]`.  Not confusing at all, I know, :)